# Windows 10 not Using Full RAM

Tags: windows, memory, windows-10

I have Windows 10 Education 64-bit installed on my HP Probook 4530 with 8GB Ram(2x4). The thing i noticed is that my system is not using full RAM. It Display and reads full RAM, but in usage it only use upto 4.1,4.2,4.3GB and remains at the same stage no matter how many softwares or webpages i open. 
What could be the issue ?

[image]

Comment: There isn't an issue.  As shown in your screenshot you simply don't have applications running that require more then 51% of your system memory.

Comment: @Ramhound this is the normal RAM usage with just one Installation in progress, nothing changes when i use apps too

Comment: Statements like "nothing changes' has specific meaning.  I find it hard to loaded a 500MB text file into Word your memory usage wouldn't change.

Comment: got it @Ramhound

Answer (score 6):

The display above is misleading. "In use" means directly used by processes. "Available" means available for use by processes but possibly also being used for something else.

At the moment, 7.9GB is being used, 4.1 by processes and 3.8 for other purposes such as caching. A small amount of memory must remain free for use by interrupts.

So all of your RAM is in use except about 2% which must remain free.

The percentage "in use" is intended to warn of cases where the system's working set gets too close to the amount of installed RAM. So a low number there is perfectly normal and doesn't indicate that RAM isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 4.1gb and have 3.7gb still available you have the full 8gbs in your system. What you are reading is what you are using not what you have installed. So your system is using the full ram. So don't worry your system is handling very well.